# In WPF how to add textbox to a collection in canvas dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

learning WPF...
I have a canvas and I have this structure:

```
  LayoutCanvas
  ----Mastergrid
      ----ChildGrid1
          ----Rectangle1
          ----Rectangle2
          ----Texbox1
      ----ChildGrid2
          ----Rectangle1
          ----Rectangle2
          ----Texbox1
etc..
```

When the user clicks on the canvas, a new childGrid gets created which houses rectangles and texboxes and that childGrid gets added to the masterGrid that houses all the childGrids. I need to be able to move the whole childGrid around in the canvas.
My problem is that I'm unable to position the textbox wherever I want within its parent grid (the childGrid). Adding the textbox goes automatically to the center of its masterGrid. Here is my code, what am I doing wrong or how else to achieve it.

```
Grid masterGrid = new Grid();
masterGrid.Width = 600;
masterGrid.Height = 600;

Grid childGrid = new Grid();
childGrid.Width = 100;
childGrid.Height = 100;
Canvas.SetLeft(childGrid, 100);
Canvas.SetTop(childGrid, 100);
masterGrid.Children.Add(childGrid);

var txt = new TextBox();
txt.Text = "New Text1";
Canvas.SetLeft(txt, 10);
Canvas.SetTop(txt, 10);
txt.Width = 100;
txt.Height = 100;
childGrid.Children.Add(txt);

LayoutCanvas.Children.Add(masterGrid);
```

EDIT
Thank you Greg M for the explanation, but when I try to play with this example, I get my textbox showing up in the same exact spot for 2 or 3 for the rowProperty value, but with 1, the textbox does go up:

```
Grid masterGrid = new Grid
{
    Width = 600,
    Height = 600
};

masterGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
masterGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
masterGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
masterGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

masterGrid.Width = 600;
masterGrid.Height = 600;

Grid childGrid = new Grid();
childGrid.Width = 100;
childGrid.Height = 100;
childGrid.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
childGrid.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
Canvas.SetLeft(childGrid, 100);
Canvas.SetTop(childGrid, 100);

var txt = new TextBox();
txt.Text = "New Text1";
Canvas.SetLeft(txt, 10);
Canvas.SetTop(txt, 10);
txt.Width = 100;
txt.Height = 100;

childGrid.Children.Add(txt);
masterGrid.Children.Add(childGrid);
LayoutCanvas.Children.Add(masterGrid);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because, as written, all controls are going to Row=0,Col=0.

You are missing:

```
masterGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
masterGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
```

Then you assign control to row/col:

```
Grid.SetRow(childGrid, 4);
```

so complete would look like this:

```
Grid masterGrid = new Grid();
masterGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
masterGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
masterGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
masterGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

Grid childGrid = new Grid();
Grid.SetRow(childGrid, 1);
Grid.SetColumn(childGrid, 1);
masterGrid.Children.Add(childGrid);
```

Your calls:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(childGrid, 100);
Canvas.SetTop(childGrid, 100);
```

were probably meant for masterGrid?  But they have no effect on childGrid since its parent is masterGrid.

or change

Grid childGrid to
Canvas childCanvas

To answer your edited question:
If you want to be able to drag and move child grids,
then you really don't want them inside another grid.
You should be adding them to a canvas.
You still need to write code to capture mousedown/drag events to move.
(not good code, but will show you things to learn)

```
    CreateGridCanvas ( 10, 10, "text 1a", "text 1b" );
    CreateGridCanvas ( 20, 210, "text 2a", "text 2b" );


  private void CreateGridCanvas ( int x, int y, string text1, string text2 )
  {
    Grid childGrid = new Grid
    {
      Width = 100,
      Height = 100,
      ShowGridLines = true
    };
    LayoutCanvas.Children.Add ( childGrid );
    Canvas.SetLeft ( childGrid, x );
    Canvas.SetTop ( childGrid, y );
    //masterGrid.Children.Add ( childGrid );
    Grid.SetRow ( childGrid, 0 );
    Grid.SetColumn ( childGrid, 0 );

    childGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add ( new ColumnDefinition () );
    childGrid.RowDefinitions.Add ( new RowDefinition () );
    childGrid.RowDefinitions.Add ( new RowDefinition () );

    TextBox txt = new TextBox
    {
      Text = text1,
      Width = 100,
      Height = 100,
      Visibility = Visibility.Visible
    };
    childGrid.Children.Add ( txt );
    Grid.SetRow ( txt, 0 );
    Grid.SetColumn ( txt, 0 );

    TextBox txt2 = new TextBox
    {
      Text = text2,
      Width = 100,
      Height = 100,
      Visibility = Visibility.Visible
    };
    childGrid.Children.Add ( txt2 );
    Grid.SetRow ( txt2, 1 );
    Grid.SetColumn ( txt2, 0 );
  }
```

Comment: `childGrid.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 4)` should be `Grid.SetRow(childGrid, 4)`. Like any other attached property, use the static getter and setter methods.

Comment: Actually, no that is what it should be.  I am setting the local value of childGrid.    Just tested.  Though your way works too.

Comment: I am not saying that it does not work. `Grid.SetRow` also calls `SetValue`. It is just a convention for cleaner code to always use the provided static getter and setter methods.  Otherwise you should also write `childGrid.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 100);`.

Comment: I'm ok with that because it is an old established method, however it is just a preference since if you look at the Microsoft Core code, you will notice that other than checking for null it just calls element.SetValue(RowProperty, value).   But that is what is great about c#, many ways to encapsulate related code into a common method where you can add error checking and related methods.
https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/ec69834f378fb98ef5f623db1c55610ac074001d/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Controls/Grid.cs

Comment: You may want to read [Attached properties in code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/attached-properties-overview?view=netdesktop-7.0#attached-properties-in-code). While you *can* also directly call GetValue and SetValue to access an attached property in code, the standard approach is to use the static getter and setter methods, which are mandatory in the declaration of the property.

Comment: I added code at bottom of my answer to answer your edited question.  There are a number of design issues that you really need to address (outside the scope of this site).  First, I don't think you need/want the mastergrid if you intend to drag the child grids around.  But I gave you an idea of how to add child grids to a canvas at different locations.